# References for the Euler function $\prod_{k=1}^\infty{(1-q^k)}$

Tags: reference-request, infinite-product

I was thinking about probability games when I stumbled upon an interesting sequence, namely

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty{(1-q^k)} = (1-q)(1-q^2)(1-q^3)...$$

I was specifically interested in a proof on whether this function converges to a non-zero value for all $q \in \mathbb{C},\ |q| < 1$.

A quick google search pointed me to Wiikipedia's ["Euler function" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function), which is exactly the function I'm looking for. However, the page lacks any links to helpful online results or resources, only referencing a couple of hardcover books and OEIS (and surprisingly a paper in German?).

Unfortunately, searching Euler's function doesn't give any relevant results as it's understandably overwhelmed by Euler's more famous (totient) function.

I'm really at a loss here, as my only lead seems to be a dead end.

Does anyone know any online resources regarding this function, or a better way to search for references specifically about *this* Euler's function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $|q|<1$, $l(q)=\sum_{k\ge 1} \log(1-q^k)$ is well-defined and it converges (as $\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{\log(1-q^k)}{q^k}=-1$), so yes sure $\phi(q)=\prod_{k\ge 1} (1-q^k)=\exp(l(q))$ converges to a non-zero value.

Comment: Please consult [OEIS sequence A010815](https://oeis.org/A010815) and its many references. Also relevant is [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function).